# Apple clangs documentation

Tags: xcode

I had an edge case with building a project I have after updating my macOS and XCode
and after looking at Apple forums my problem
solved by adding this compilation flag `-fno-objc-msgsend-selector-stubs` to my build process.
Naturally I tried to find the documentation for this flag, but there was nothing on `man`, and
nothing on the official open source llvm clang cli reference guide. Furthermore, I noticed that
this flag has to do with XCode and is exclusive to Apple's clang, so is this thing documented
anywhere? How could I find it if there were no other people with the same problem as me?
Is Apple's clang open source? And if yes, where are the sources?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer.

Google gives an issue in the open source llvm  as first hit https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56034 So yes undocumented by Apple  but llvm development has it.

Apple's clang/llvm is not open source so we can't see the source.

Yes Apple's documentation has got worse.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, though I don't thing there will be an acceptable answer in my question (I will probably archive it).